# Disable background color when using Alt-Tab in XFCE

Tags: xfce

I am using XFCE with Numix theme and when I press alt-tab, I get that ugly red background, during the alt-tab presses. That red is very disturbing to the eyes. Yes, I can change it with another theme, but the background remains.

How can I disable that background?

Here is a small gif, thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Window manager tweaks" -> "Draw frame around selected window while cycling" = false

---

I could swear there used to be a setting that displayed only the border and not the background, but I can't find it now.